# How to automatically set optimal frame width of Emacs?

Tags: emacs, configuration, resize, zooming, elisp

How to automatically set optimal frame width of Emacs?

When open a file with Emacs from command line, how to let it automatically set the frame size such that

- width is 2 characters wider than the widest row or the computer screen width, which ever is smaller
- height is 80 rows, or the computer screen height, which ever is smaller?

Comment: 800 rows?  how big is your monitor?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `find-file-hook` which sets your frame's size.  You'll need things like display-width and display-height, and you'll need to loop through the whole file computing the width of each line (using `forward-line` to move to the next line, `end-of-line` to go the end of the line and `current-column` to find the width).  And you'll probably need to fiddle with off-by-one details in order to account for things like the menu-bar, the fringes, ...

Me?  I prefer to declare that files should not go over 80 columns so I don't need to adjust the frame width.

Answer (score 0):

This is just what libraries [`fit-frame.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/fit-frame.el) and [`autofit-frame.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/autofit-frame.el) are for. See also http://www.emacswiki.org/FrameSize.